# Strong-pm does not run with NODE_ENV=production

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I have followed the [Setting up a production host](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Setting+up+a+production+host#Settingupaproductionhost-Setenvironmentvariables) & [Environment Specific Configuration](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration), and specify the `NODE_ENV=production` in while installing the strong-pm.

However, after I deploy the application, I find the application did not load `component-config.production.json`, it will still loading `component-config.json`.

How can I let the application to run in `production` environment.

This is how I build and deploy the application:

```
slc build --npm
slc deploy http://username:password:the-ip-address
```

Answer (score 0):

strong-pm is a multi-app runtime that you deploy apps to. If you want to set the environment for an app, you need to set it for the app, not strong-pm.

You will need to run something like `slc ctl env-set 1 NODE_ENV=production` to set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable for app 1.